# Write a program to prompt for square height h and print the even numbers in a square shape?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm not sure how to do this. I know how to print a square shape by prompting for row and col, but don't quite understand how to only prompt for height and print an array of even numbers.

```
col = eval(input("Enter the number of columns: "))

row = eval(input("Enter the number of rows: "))

for j in range(row):
   for i in range(col):
   print("*", end=" ")
print()
```

this is how I would set up printing a square of asterisks, but how would I do this while only prompting for height and printing out even numbers? For example, if my height is "3", it should print out an array that looks like this:

```
0 2 4
6 8 10
12 14 16
```

Comment: `eval` instead of `int`? Live fast and dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

Using `next()` on an `iterator` of the numbers:

```
h = 3
ns = iter(range(0,h**2*2,2))
for r in range(h):
    for c in range(h):
        print(next(ns), end='\t')
    print()
```

which gives:

```
0   2   4   
6   8   10  
12  14  16
```

---

Using `slicing` and `str.join`:

```
h = 4
ns = list(range(0,h**2*2,2))
for r in range(0,len(ns),h):
    print(" ".join(str(c) + "\t" for c in ns[r:r+h]))
```

which gives:

```
0    2   4   6  
8    10  12  14 
16   18  20  22 
24   26  28  30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach by making a nested list and printing it out using a formatting function. Can replace the list comprehension with a generator comprehension for large lists.

```
def print_even_matrix(h):
    l = [[2*(i + j) for j in range(h)] for i in range(0, h**2, h)]
    listtab = lambda x: '\t'.join(map(str, x))
    print '\n'.join(map(listtab, l))

>>> print_even_matrix(3)
0       2       4
6       8       10
12      14      16
>>> print_even_matrix(4)
0       2       4       6
8       10      12      14
16      18      20      22
24      26      28      30
```